# ¿Cómo ignorar los cambios de permisos en git (chmod)?

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y uso git para gestión de versiones. El problema que tengo es que si cambio los permisos del directorio, me aparecen que los archivos fueron modificados, pero cuando utilizo `git diff` para realizar la observación de los cambios me aparece una lista como la siguiente:

```bash
diff --git a/assets/images/icon-32-bcache.png b/assets/images/icon-32-bcache.png
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/assets/images/icon-32-help.png b/assets/images/icon-32-help.png
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Dichos cambios los considero basura para estar en un commit ¿existe un comando que ignore dichos cambios?.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Para ignorar los cambios de permisos en [git](/questions/tagged/git), se realiza con:

```
% git config core.fileMode false
```

Más información en [Manual GIT Config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/git-config.html#_variables):

> core.fileMode: Si es falso, son ignoradas las diferencias de bit
>   ejecutable entre el índice y el árbol de trabajo.

Pregunta similar (en inglés): 
[How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Answer (score 9):

Para ignorar los cambios en los permisos de los archivos, debes ejecutar:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Como veo que no te interesan estos cambios en absoluto, puedes hacer que esta configuración sea global (es decir que así sea para todos los repositorios de tu usuario):

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Referencias:

- [Versión actual del manual de Git en inglés](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)
- [Pregunta similar en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Comment: La segunda opción (global) no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Muy raro eso. ¿La primera sí te funcionó?

Comment: Si, la primera no tuve problema alguno.