# GIT cambia los permisos de los archivos después de hacer pull?

Tags: php, git, servidor

Mi problema es el siguiente pongo un ejemplo:

Mi archivo `index.php` en producción esta con los permisos correctos y funcionando

Cuando realizo un cambio y ejecuto pull en el server ese archivo `index.php` queda sin permisos de ejecución.

Ha alguien le  ha pasado algo similar o tienen idea de como solucionarlo

<sub>Tengo entendio que GIT no cambia permisos bueno eso dice la documentación..</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Bastaba con investigar un poco más.

Te encontré esto:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Sirve para ignorar los cambios en los permisos de los archivos.

Más información en: [Ignorar cambios en los permisos del archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/969/c%c3%b3mo-ignorar-los-cambios-de-permisos-en-git-chmod)